# Unable to write to /tmp directory in macOS, unable to correct permissions: “Operation not permitted”

Tags: macos, permissions, chmod, osx-el-capitan

macOS El Capitan (10.11) is unable to install any software updates or install any software because the `/tmp` and the `/private/tmp` folders don't seem to be writeable.

Running this:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /
```

Gives me this error:

```
unable to set owner and group on "tmp" Error 1 Operation not permitted
unable to set permissions on "tmp" Error 1 Operation not permitted
```

Is there a way to manually delete the tmp folders and recreate them?
When I tried renaming or deleting `/tmp` or `/private/tmp` I kept getting operation not permitted. `sudo chmod 1777` also failed in the same way on both `/tmp` and `/private/tmp` folders

Disk Utility says the disk is healthy with no issues detected when running first aid.

Is there any way to redirect the `tmp` location to another writeable folder?

Comment: Did you disable SIP first? From Recovery; Terminal `csrutil disable`

Comment: I have the same problem. Followed Tetsujin's advice, restarted in recovery mode, and ran `csrutil disable`. After that, I was able to execute `repair_packages` with success and was able to access /tmp as usual. However, after going back to recovery mode and executing `csrutil enable`, my system is having the same problem. It seems the only way I can gain access to /tmp is by disabling System Integrity Protection.

Comment: I ended up going back to recovery mode and executing `csrutil disable`. After a restart, I removed tmp folder: `sudo rm /tmp; sudo rm /private/tmp`, created tmp folder `sudo mkdir /private/tmp; sudo chown root:wheel /private/tmp; sudo chmod 1777 /private/tmp`, created the symlink: `sudo ln -s /private/tmp /tmp`, and ran `repair_pacakges` again. After going back to recovery mode and running `csrutil enable`, all is working again! However, the permissions of /private/tmp used to be `drwxrwxrwt@` and now they are `drwxrwxrwt`. I'm unsure what the `@` is and if this will cause me problems.

Comment: @AndrewFerk: see these posts http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42177/what-does-signify-in-unix-file-permissions http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-does-the-mean-in-ls-l for explanation of the `@` **extended permissions** marker

Comment: [Another, simpler, solution](https://github.com/Kevin-De-Koninck/Clean-Me/issues/23#issuecomment-617059971): apparently, `sudo mkdir /private/tmp` followed by `sudo chmod +t /private/tmp` is enough.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. Reboot your Mac into [recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)
2. Open Utilities menu in the top bar > open Terminal

   ```
   csrutil disable
   ```
3. Reboot
4. Remove the tmp folder

   ```
   sudo rm -i /tmp
   sudo rm -i /private/tmp
   ```
5. Create tmp folder

   ```
   sudo mkdir /private/tmp
   sudo chown root:wheel /private/tmp
   sudo chmod 1777 /private/tmp
   ```
6. Create the symlink

   ```
   sudo ln -s /private/tmp /tmp
   ```
7. Run `repair_packages` (you may not need to do this)

   ```
   sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /
   ```
8. Reboot back to recovery mode and run

   ```
   csrutil enable
   ```
9. Reboot

---

*Props to Andrew Ferk for figuring out a fix; pulling out your comment as a community wiki answer so it's more readable.*

Comment: Thank you!!! I had spent 3 days pulling my hair out over this. No idea how the permissions got so screwed in the first place, but one day I turned on the mac to a selection of warnings, programs not working and an inability to install anything. This fixed that problem.

Comment: Why did you make this CW?

Comment: Because I didn't want to get credit for an answer which I merely converted from someone else's comment

Comment: Alright, cool. BTW, I did not see your comment until now since there was no @Fiksdal.

Comment: 10.13: sudo: /usr/libexec/repair_packages: command not found

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo chmod 1777 /private/tmp
```

Did it for me.

Comment: ^This^ is why the accepted answer works, and this solution is much safer! No need to nuke existing directories then recreate them with different permissions.

Comment: Thank you so much. My machine re-enables `csrutil` on startup so I couldn't take the steps in the other answer. This answer is a million times more useful.

For any potential future googlers - this solved my problem with Cisco AnyConnect saying "failed to determine valid temporary file folder."

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by restoring my system from a Time Machine Backup. But the other suggestions in the comments are worth trying too.

Answer (score 0):

If you got this message in terminal (or iTerm) using maxOS Mojave

> Operation not permitted

It turned out I needed to add my terminal app to the Settings.app "Security & Privacy" > "Full Disk Access"
(I added both `terminal.app` and `iTerm.app`)

Answer (score -1):

Try to create and modify permissions on `/private/tmp` folder without running `csrutil disable`. This worked for me, after trying unsuccessfully to delete and the error message on boot is gone.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please don't post an answer to confirm that another answer worked.  The site's Q&A format reserves answers for solutions to the question, and each answer should contribute another solution.  The way to indicate that an answer was useful is to invest a little time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://superuser.com/help/privileges) to upvote answers you like.