# ssh-agent service stop starting at login on Mac OS 10.11

Tags: macos, boot, ssh, osx-el-capitan, ssh-agent

I'm currently facing a little issue about the *ssh-agent* service. I rebooted my computer today after removing a Boot Camp partition. Since then, ssh-agent no longer starts automatically at login.

I use this agent really often with Git and multiple SSH keys and have not seen a problem like this before. I can't find any errors about ssh-agent in the "Console" application.

How can I check the service configuration? What can I do to make it work again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They chose to realign macOS behavior (Sierra) with the mainstream OpenSSH. You'll maybe find an explanation to make it work again here:

[SSH-agent does not automatically load passphrases on the OSX Sierra keychain during startup](https://blog.elao.com/en/tech/ssh-agent-does-not-automatically-load-passphrases-on-the-osx-sierra-keychain/)

> Engineering has determined that this issue behaves as intended based on the following information: That’s expected. We re-aligned our behavior with the mainstream OpenSSH in this area. You can fix this pretty easily by running ssh-add -A in your rc script if you want your keys to always be loaded.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer... Seems to doesn't be the solution for me. This is my `ssh-agent` which is not started... All the keys are already loaded correctly but when I ran something like `ssh-add -A` I receive the message `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` so I must run : `eval ssh-agent $SHELL`...

Comment: I haven't found a validation solution for my problem but your article help me a lot :)

Comment: Finally I found the valid answer here... There was a problem after downloading MacOS Sierra but not installing it... https://superuser.com/questions/1133065/unable-to-write-to-tmp-osx-unable-to-correct-permissions-operation-not-permitt#comment1629612_1133065