# Cannot change /tmp folder permissions in macOS Catalina (10.15) Beta (Build: 19A487l)

Tags: macos, permissions, tunnelblick, macos-catalina

I am trying to install [Tunnelblick](https://tunnelblick.net/), it shows this error

```
The tmp system folder (/tmp) is not secure.
```

Here's the symlink permission

```
$ ll /tmp
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root admin 11 Jun 23 21:29 /tmp -> private/tmp

$ ll /private
drwxrwxrwt  8 root wheel  256 Jun 24 21:23 tmp
```

Then I found [this post](https://superuser.com/q/1133065/167207) and followed the steps [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1136881/167207) and I reboot to recovery mode, and disable `csrutil`, and I'm still not able to delete the `/tmp` *(Readonly operation...)*

Is there any other way to change the permission? I just want to install Tunnelblick.

Comment: That's an odd error message. Although /tmp is a symlink here, the permissions of /private/tmp seem completely normal.

Comment: `lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 11 Sep 27  2018 /tmp -> private/tmp` The **group** is `wheel` when I check in macOS 10.14, the `wheel` & `admin` is the only difference

Answer (score 1):

The offical answer to this is "press Continue" or download latest Beta.

https://tunnelblick.net/cCatalina.html
https://github.com/Tunnelblick/Tunnelblick/issues/554